# How can I install the Safari web browser?

Tags: wine, browser

I want to install the Apple Safari browser on my Ubuntu 10.04 machine in order to test the latest HTML5 and CSS3 features of the browser.

I believe it is possible to use WINE for this but I want to know which version WINE should be used and which version of Windows I should emulate. Will Wine be able to support all the CSS3 animations or should I install Winetricks ?

Comment: Is Safari's support for HTML5/CSS3 any different than Chromium/Chrome's? (Both are WebKit browsers.) Probably not much. Don't believe Apple's hype.

Comment: Actually it is more complete especially in terms of CSS3 - http://www.findmebyip.com/litmus#html5-web-applications

Comment: the only big thing has been the 3d css and that has just been pushed into the latest Chrome dev release which you can follow by getting the dev channel for early access: http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the latest HTML 5 features, you'll want to use Safari 5, not Safari 4.

Your go-to resource for running applications in Wine is the [Wine Application Database (AppDB)](http://appdb.winehq.org/), which incorporates invaluable test results from outside of the Ubuntu community and should have the most up-to-date information on compatibility.

The [most recent test results](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=20398) report success running Safari 5 in Wine 1.3.2, which is available in the [WineHQ Repository](http://www.winehq.org/download/deb). Right now there are not any special installation instructions posted. Typically this means you don't have to do any special setup, but you should be open to the possibility that the users posting results for Safari 5 have wrongly assumed that you know to refer back to some part of the Safari 4 installation instructions. If things aren't working as well as reported, try applying the [installation instructions for Safari 4](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=16867).

Answer (score 1):

There are detailed instructions at: http://www.junauza.com/2010/02/installing-and-running-safari-4-on.html