# Opera and Safari installation

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, browser, opera

How do I install Opera and Safari on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32 bit? Can anyone help? Opera I downloaded but could not get it installed. On the other hand I did not try Safari, even I don't have any idea if Safari has a version for Ubuntu.

Comment: Those are actually two questions, please open a new separate question for one of the two applications (unless you find a similar one) and [edit] this question, so that it only asks about the other. For Opera see https://askubuntu.com/q/316193/175814, for Safari see https://askubuntu.com/q/4959/175814.

Comment: Valuable advice David Foerster but I downloaded Opera for 32-bit Linux. Thanks.

Answer (score 31):

Safari doesn't have Linux version. But you can run it using Wine.
First install Wine.

```
sudo apt-get install -y wine
```

Then create, download and build directory.

```
mkdir -p ~/build/safari
cd  ~/build/safari
```

Download Safari ( version for windows)

```
wget http://appldnld.apple.com/Safari5/041-5487.20120509.INU8B/SafariSetup.exe
```

Open using wine.

```
wine SafariSetup.exe
```

Comment: It installs without error but unfortunately, Safari doesn't actually run. The window loads but is almost completely unresponsive and refuses to load any pages.

Comment: Safari is no longer supported in Windows and running it with Wine will result in outdated and unpredictable browser. Not good for testing!

Comment: Note that this solution is from Aug '15, and latest Safari supported on Windows is 5.1.7 and most recent Safari version is 10.1 as of Apr 17

Comment: Try install microsoft core fonts if wine can't run: http://web.archive.org/web/20080717035040/http://www.ubuntu-unleashed.com/2008/03/howto-install-safari-on-ubuntu-with.html

Comment: wine supports safari5 and it's too old version is there any for update safari version inside wine

Comment: You can more easily install Safari with PlayOnLinux but you will get the same outdated Safari 5 version

Answer (score 16):

1. The latest version of Opera 27 is only for 64-bit systems. If you want to use Opera you should choose an older version:

[Opera 12.16 download link for 32-bit Linux](http://arc.opera.com/pub/opera/linux/1216/opera_12.16.1860_i386.deb)

**UPDATE: Opera restored 32-bit Linux support since Opera 35**: [Opera 35 32 bit](http://operasoftware.pc.cdn.bitgravity.com/ftp/pub/opera/desktop/35.0.2066.37/linux/opera-stable_35.0.2066.37_i386.deb)

Browse [Opera official site](http://Opera.com) for necessary packages.

2. Safari doesn't have Linux version.You cannot run it natively in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Opera web browser comes with built-in ad blocker, battery saver and free VPN. To install Opera in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install opera
```

Apple hasn't a version of Safari that is compatible with Wine since 2010. Microsoft Edge is similar in features to Safari and has the additional advantage that .deb files for installing Edge web browser available from [Download Microsoft Insider Chnannels](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download?platform=linux-deb) to easily install it in Ubuntu with the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ./microsoft-edge-beta_101.0.1210.26-1_amd64 # replace with the name of the .deb file that you downloaded
```

Microsoft Edge web browser includes Bing AI with GPT 4.

You can also install Microsoft Edge browser as a flatpak app by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install flatpak  
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
flatpak install flathub com.microsoft.Edge
```

To run Microsoft Edge:

```
flatpak run com.microsoft.Edge
```