# Webkit - how to test your website on Safari 10?

Tags: kubuntu, 17.04, webkit

I am on Linux - Ubuntu/ Kubuntu 17.04 and I need to test my website on the latest Safari browser. I found this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/273185/testing-a-website-using-safari-on-linux) so I downloaded the release from this [site](https://webkitgtk.org/). This is what I downloaded webkitgtk-2.16.1.tar.xz

I unzipped it but how can I use/ run it?

I also came across this https://saucelabs.com/ but not sure how reliable it is. Any other open source options?

Comment: Instructions for installing Webkit-GTK+ are here: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/cvs/x/webkitgtk.html

Comment: It is far far far easier to use online tools then install all these browsers.

Comment: Run Safari in wine see - https://askubuntu.com/questions/585209/opera-and-safari-installation

Answer (score 8):

I installed [midori](http://midori-browser.org/download/choose/) browser which usess the webkit rendering engine.  I managed to reproduce the error on a page that was initially found using a safari browser.

Answer (score 6):

As Aurovrata said, Midori is working.

On Debian there's also the browser "Web" which is preinstalled:

https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Web

It's also a webkit browser and I was able to fix my issue with it, on Ubuntu (and Debian) it is provided by the `epiphany-browser` package:

```
sudo apt install epiphany-browser
```

Comment: that's a good find, here is a comparison of [Midori vs Epiphany](https://www.techdrivein.com/2011/01/midori-vs-epiphany-review.html) which seems comparable.   Both browsers are available in the distribution now.

Answer (score 1):

IMO it is far far far easier to use the online tools then to install hundreds of browsers.

See - https://www.browserstack.com/screenshots or similar tools, you can test hundreds of browsers very very very easily.

If you wish to run safari, IMO, easiest to use wine. See [Opera and Safari installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/585209/opera-and-safari-installation)

Comment: tried that already. safari on wine is version 5 only. i need safari 10.

Comment: what is IMO btw?

Comment: that smells. Personally as I said I use the online tools for the reasons you are running into, it is difficult to impossible to test all these browsers by installing them or running multiple OS. If you follow web standards for HTML code, use HTML5, and clear your css you should be fine, but personally I just test the big browsers such as IE , firefox, and chrome . East to test on my  phone, done. Let the online tools do the rest.

Comment: Try this - http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/ . The problem is that although there are standards for web servers / HTML and css, each browser has its own defaults. I zero out the css and then write css works almost always. Also no 2 browsers will always render the page 100 % the same if I come close enough on the major browsers - Done.

Comment: it is the issue of grid layout from bootstrap/ foundation zurb that i am facing. nothing to do with html or css. the grid layout does not work on safari but all other browsers are fine. Apple stuff is really annoying!

Comment: Yes in that case you are probably better off rendering a page based on browser identification. See https://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Optimizing_content_for_different_browsers:_the_RIGHT_way . Personally I use browser detection but at least you have options. Also, although I use new and advanced features, when seeking the most cross platform compatibility there is always a lag as not all browsers keep pace. Either write to the lowest common technology, detect brower/ features or don't  try to please them all depending on your needs.

Comment: Browser / Feature detection is a PITA as technology always changes. So as soon as Safari updates it's supported features , or as soon as there is a new version of HTML, you have to re-write all your browser / feature detection so IMO this is the least desirable option of the 3. For professional sites go least common denominator and let features lag. For personal sites I write the code I want and tell users who complain to  my code is HTMO / css compliant and they need file a bug report with their browser.

Comment: but how do you *debug* on those online tools? I need the result of `console`